# BigblueButton serves only on HTTP not HTTPS

Tags: http, installation, https, bigbluebutton

I installed on Ubuntu 16.04, 4 cores, 8Gb RAM. I ran the cerbot command and it returned a congratulatory message that it's successful.
This is my first time installing BigBlueButton. I followed the process and all seemed fine until I tried running it on HTTPS `https://live.oltega.com`, and it returned

```
This site can’t be reached
live.oltega.com refused to connect.
Try: Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

when I served the same on HTTP `http://live.oltega.com` it worked well but displays a blue screen because it can only work on HTTPS. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

After obtaining a Let's Encrypt certificate, you should configure the BBB components like Nginx and Freeswith to use HTTPS.
Follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html#using-lets-encrypt).
The summary is :

1-Configure FreeSWITCH for using SSL
Edit the file /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx and change the protocol and port on the proxy_pass line as shown bellow

```
    location /ws {
  proxy_pass https://203.0.113.1:7443;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  proxy_read_timeout 6h;
  proxy_send_timeout 6h;
  client_body_timeout 6h;
  send_timeout 6h;
}
```

2- Configure BigBlueButton to load session via HTTPS
Edit /usr/share/bbb-web/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties and update the property bigbluebutton.web.serverURL to use HTTPS:

```
#----------------------------------------------------
# This URL is where the BBB client is accessible. When a user successfully
# enters a name and password, she is redirected here to load the client.
bigbluebutton.web.serverURL=https://bigbluebutton.example.com
```

Next, edit the file /usr/share/red5/webapps/screenshare/WEB-INF/screenshare.properties and update the property jnlpUrl and jnlpFile to HTTPS:

```
streamBaseUrl=rtmp://bigbluebutton.example.com/screenshare
jnlpUrl=https://bigbluebutton.example.com/screenshare
jnlpFile=https://bigbluebutton.example.com/screenshare/screenshare.jnlp
```

Next, you should do the following command:

```
$ sudo sed -e 's|http://|https://|g' -i /var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml
```

Open /usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/settings.yml editing and change:

```
kurento:
    wsUrl: ws://bbb.example.com/bbb-webrtc-sfu
```

to

```
kurento:
    wsUrl: wss://bbb.example.com/bbb-webrtc-sfu
```

and also

```
note:
    enabled: true
    url: http://bbb.example.com/pad
```

to

```
note:
    enabled: true
    url: https://bbb.example.com/pad
```

3- Next, modify the creation of recordings so they are served via HTTPS
Edit /usr/local/bigbluebutton/core/scripts/bigbluebutton.yml and change the value for playback_protocol as follows:

```
playback_protocol: https
```

4-If you have installed the API demos, edit /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/demo/bbb_api_conf.jsp and change the value of BigBlueButtonURL use HTTPS.

```
// This is the URL for the BigBlueButton server
String BigBlueButtonURL = "https://bigbluebutton.example.com/bigbluebutton/";
```

5-Finally, to apply all of the configuration changes made, you must restart all components of BigBlueButton:

```
$ sudo bbb-conf --restart
```

Comment: Can you update your answer to match BBB version 2.5.2, because they made changes in some files